# Reading Json object name in arduino

Tags: arduino-uno

How do I read the Json object name in arduino? For { "pi" : "3.14" }, I want the arduino to automatically read the object name "pi" and then th value "3.14"
I'm using arduino Uno.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a brilliant JSON library called ArduinoJSON. It can be installed using the arduino library manager.

See https://bblanchon.github.io/ArduinoJson/doc/decoding/ for further details.

To loop through the keys, you can use:
https://bblanchon.github.io/ArduinoJson/api/jsonobject/begin_end/

or if you know the key, you can do jsonObject["pi"] to get the value